# why is it showing duplicates of all my inputs?

Tags: python

```
pres = ["Kennedy", "Lincoln", "Washington", "Trump"]

for presidents in pres:
    print ("%s" % presidents)

add = input("Please enter a president: ")
if add not in pres:
    pres.append(add)
pres.insert(-1,add)
add = input("Please enter a president: ")
if add not in pres:
    pres.append(add)
pres.insert(-1,add)
add = input("Please enter a president: ")
if add not in pres:
    pres.append(add)
pres.insert(-1,add)
add = input("Please enter a president: ")
if add not in pres:
    pres.append(add)
pres.insert(-1,add)
print (pres)
```

also does this program cover this question correctly: Write a program that contains a list holding the names of four USA presidents. Use any presidents you wish. Then, run a loop that adds four more presidents to the list. Call another function with the list as its sole argument. This second function should sort the list and then loop through the list to print each president's name on its own line.

for instance it shows my output as:

```
Please enter a president: obama
Please enter a president: eisenhower
Please enter a president: truman
Please enter a president: obama
['Kennedy', 'Lincoln', 'Washington', 'Trump', 'obama', 'obama', 'eisenhower', 'eisenhower', 'truman', 'obama', 'truman']
```

Comment: It is showing duplicate because you are adding it two times - first using `pres.append(add)` and then using `pres.insert(-1,add)`. You don't need the last statement because you are already appending if the president is not in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
add = input("Please enter a president: ")
if add not in pres:
    pres.append(add) #adding president if name is not present.
pres.insert(-1,add) #adding president again(doesn't matter if present or not)
```

So remove the second insert.

```
 add = input("Please enter a president: ")
if add not in pres:
    pres.append(add)
```

Also, you have to run a loop to add four more presidents so:

```
For i in range(4):
    add = input("Please enter a president: ")
    if add not in pres:
       pres.append(add);
    else:
       i = i-1;  #to add president, not already present.
```

Lastly, create a function and pass the president-names as argument, use sort function(use sort() or sorted() ) and print the list.

Hope this help.